# Modify snippet of snipmate without changing submodule

Tags: git, vim, git-submodules, vim-plugin, snipmate

I installed the snipmate plugin and it works really well. I had to modify a snipped but that obviously resulted in a submodule change. Is there a better way to do this?

**Note:** I'm using pathogen to manage plugins.

Comment: Everytime I see your questions I want to start my answers with "Yo Dawg!". And, eventually, post the content of your question inside my answer.

Comment: @romainl Dawg don't mind that. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SnipMate looks for snippets in a few locations. One of those locations, the default location IIRC, is:

```
~/.vim/snippets/
```

So you can put your custom snippets there.